# How to select <div> with ionic and appium

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, appium

I always used findElement(By.id) or findElement(By.className) but with the tags used on ionic i dont know how select the element , the code of the app is:

```
<div (click)="openclose('otras')" *ngIf="!emptyOtras">
<p class="info uppercase">Otras / Tango<span class="iconDetail" ><ion-icon [ngClass]="{'openDetail': !oOtras, 'closeDetail' : oOtras}" md="detail-vtr" ios="detail-vtr" slot="end"></ion-icon></span></p>
<ion-list lines="none" *ngIf="oOtras">
  <div *ngFor="let orden of ordenes" class="orden">
    <div *ngIf="orden?.ESTADO!='INI' && orden?.ESTADO!='PEN' && orden?.ESTADO!='COM'">
      <p *ngIf="orden?.toa" class="estado {{orden?.ESTADO}}"   > 
         Estado: {{orden?.ESTADO | toaName}}
      </p>
      <ion-item mode="ios"  (click)="detalle(orden)"  detail="false">  
          <ion-label text-wrap >
            <p class="title-orden">Nº de orden: <span>{{orden.IDEN_ORDEN}}</span></p>
            <h4 class="actividad">{{orden.ACTIVIDAD}}</h4>
            <h4 class="hora">Horario: {{orden.AGENHORA | filterTime: orden.toa?true:false}}</h4>
          </ion-label>
          <ion-icon md="detail-vtr" ios="detail-vtr" slot="end"></ion-icon>

      </ion-item>
    </div>
  </div>
</ion-list>
```

This is the line over i have must work:

```
<div (click)="openclose('otras')" *ngIf="!emptyOtras">
```

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In this case u have to use Xpath

This one is for your element, I checked it, should work:

```
findElement(By.xpath("//p[@class = 'info uppercase']/ancestor::div"));
```

Comment: I used the code you give me and it's not working,  the message in console is:               [debug] [35m[AndroidBootstrap][39m [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Finding '//p[@class = 'info uppercase']/ancestor::div' using 'XPATH' with the contextId: '' multiple: false
[debug] [35m[AndroidBootstrap][39m [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Returning result: {"status":7,"value":"No element found"}                                                    
The code in the application not have changed

Comment: @LorenaC.EstrellaR. Please double check, this Xpath is working based on html you provided. See screenshot I just added.

Comment: I not sure because the console give me not found the element with xpath. I look this line on the console:

[BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Finding '//p[@class = 'info uppercase']/ancestor::div' using 'XPATH' with the contextId: '' multiple: false

the part in bold makes suposed that with id it´s ok. I had change the type selector for id and it´s working:

driver.findElement(By.id("p")).click(); 

But realy i dont know way